# How to install BDR on debian 9 stretch

Tags: postgresql

how do i install 2ndquadrant on dbian 9 stretch?

i tried to install as setup routine as described [here](http://bdr-project.org/docs/next/installation-packages.html#INSTALLATION-PACKAGES-DEBIAN)
but it seems like there are no releases for stretch available? doese anyone know how to install it anyway?

Comment: Install from source, or use a supported distro.

Comment: since stretch wasnt excluded in the installment instructions i expected it to be available. i switched back to jessie an all works fine.

Comment: Are there any plans to support Stretch anytime in the future?

Comment: New OS releases are usually supported when the next BDR release is done. No active customers have requested stretch, so it's not currently a priority.